# Sharepoint 2013 Connect Search Box Web Part (Provider) with Custom Web Part (Consumer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I need to use connected WebParts to build a custom webpart that gets data from the search box WebPart on the search results page. Which, from exporting it, I think it's this class: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchBoxScriptWebPart

The problem is finding what Interface to use and how to use it.

Is this even possible? I mean, can we connect OOTB Webpart to a custom WebPart?

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the ootb implementation of the searchresults webpart with e.g. ilspy? I assume it would be possible. The search webpart infrastructure is factored for connecting.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not easy. There seems to be a lot of other webparts Involved. The only interface I could find which both the search box and results use, from another base class, is IScriptControl, which seems to generic already. 

Probably the best way to do this is to make a webpart that inherits SearchResultsWebPart.

We are working around another way now. A Simpler one. Thanks though.